# Count number of dates in a interval using between on postgress timestamp return 0 records all the time

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a simple postgress table.

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA".testdate
(
    data timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
)
```

I have the following data inside it:

```
'2018-01-01 14:13:48.991'
'2018-01-01 14:13:49.835'
'2018-01-01 14:13:51.135'
'2018-01-01 14:14:48.068'
'2018-01-01 14:14:49.08'
'2018-01-01 14:14:50.03'
'2018-01-01 14:14:50.952'
'2018-01-01 14:14:51.794'
'2018-01-01 14:14:52.671'
'2018-01-01 14:14:53.552'
'2018-01-01 14:14:54.997'
```

I try to use this query to find how many dates are in a specific interval :

```
SELECT COUNT(1) NUMBER FROM  "SCHEMA".TESTDATE WHERE  DATA BETWEEN to_date('01-01-2018 14:13:43','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and to_date('01-01-2018 15:13:45','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

Why this return 0 records ? 
I also tried from java using PreparedStatement setTimestamp method   instead the two dates from the example and same problem.

```
 Date now=new Date();
 Date oneHourEarly=UTILS.addHours(now,-1);
 ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(((java.util.Date) now).getTime()));
 ps.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(((java.util.Date) oneHourEarly).getTime()));
```

What am i doing wrong ?I am using PostgresSQL version 9.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_date()` returns a `date` (without a  time)  not a `timestamp`. So both functions return the same **date**: `2018-01-01`

You need to use `to_timestamp()`:

```
select count(*) as number 
FROM testdate 
WHERE DATA BETWEEN to_timestamp('01-01-2018 14:13:43','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and to_timestamp('01-01-2018 15:13:45','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

I prefer standard SQL ISO timestamp literals over the `to_timestamp` (or `to_date`) function

```
select count(*) as number 
FROM testdate 
WHERE DATA BETWEEN timestamp '2018-01-01 14:13:43' and timestamp '2018-01-01 15:13:45';
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/ARXQ27306

Comment: Ok i understand this part.Thanks for help.But using java prepared statement with setTimestamp method why return 0 records ?